# Math Ounces in gold

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

Approximately 2,720,000 oz of gold went into the manufacturing of electronic equipment in a certain country in 1 year. This was 17% of all the gold mined in that country that year. How many ounces of gold were mined in that country that year?

Comment: What is $2,720,000 ounces $17\% of.  $.17\times????= 2,720,000$

Answer (score 2):

Consider using a simple proportion rule. 2.720.000 is to 17% just like ___ is to 100%

Comment: How many ounces of gold were mined in that country that year?

Comment: @MysteriousBeauty RGS gave you a good starting point to answer the question.

Comment: I don't understand the downvote either.

Comment: I have NEVER been on this website before. And today, for the first time, I have only asked 2 questions on this website. Why am I getting a down vote?

Comment: @MysteriousBeauty this website is a Q&A for maths questions, yes, but we encourage people to share their thoughts and attempts at a problem before we give them the answer. I tried giving you a significant hint, in the hope that you can take it and learn something new. Can I make the hint clearer?

Comment: I’ll be more blunt: people don’t like helping unless they’ve seen that you’ve tried (hence my original comment). They’ll downvote if they sense laziness.

Comment: I did try this calculation. And the calculator and submit to my question, was wrong. That is why I asked ONE additional question. In hopes to get a better determination. How rude. When someone has already attempted the calculation and even the computer states that it was wrong.

Comment: @MysteriousBeauty I am not saying you didn't try. I'm just saying I have no idea what you tried. That is why I would be glad if you could edit your question to include the calculation you tried and the result you got.

Comment: RGS - I prefer you not answer. I recieved a -3 downvote on my first day here, because You did not like my answer. First, you could have asked me what calculations I have already used, with the calculator and computer. NOT rushed to down vote. It gives this websites a bad vibe when old members are TOO quick to make a newcomer get a down vote, on their second question, ever on this website.

Comment: @MysteriousBeauty I didn't downvote your question, just so you know!

Comment: ${2720000\over {17 \over 100}}={272000000\over 17}=16000000$ not even 2 minutes to type out doing math as I go I think.